# Retrieve User Details and Roles for an Azure AD application using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm attempting to get user details for a particular enterprise application in Azure AD, using the Microsoft Graph API.

I'm able to successfully retrieve users of the application using:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{objectId}/appRoleAssignedTo
```

However, the users details are left out; such as, contact details, email.  It also has a duplicate entry for each role assigned to a user.

I'm able to get these user details if I query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

However, this retrieves all users in the organization, and I've not been successful with filtering the list in the query for a given application.

Using the $expand operator does not seem implemented either.

Seems like this would be a common use case for an application; Who are my users and what are their roles and details?  How would one best approach this with the Graph API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Individually,

You can get the [appRoles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request) of an Azure AD application using the below query.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/serviceprincipals/07fce81e-8069-4ccb-9775-63f96d1f4e53
```

and check the appRoles property.

And you can get the user details using the below query.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/4ef105cc-508b-41c4-a5d2-7d41f2244c4c
```

And you can get the group details using the below query.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/0023c709-3556-4296-a6ab-6df2a0a1113c
```

In your case you need to call the same call that you specified

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/07fce81e-8069-4ccb-9775-63f96d1f4e53/appRoleAssignedTo
```

This will return all the users and groups assigned app roles and you can pull the principal id from these [app role assignment objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/approleassignment?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) as shown below which are nothing but the userid of the user that the role was assigned to and in the groups case its the group id of the group which gives the group details.

You can differentiate user and group by principaltype and according to that you can call the above http calls(User or group) and get those details.

The duplicate ones need to be coded on our end to avoid it.

My Example JSON Data:-

```
For getting users and groups assigned app roles
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/07fce81e-8069-4ccb-9775-63f96d1f4e53/appRoleAssignedTo
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#servicePrincipals('07fce81e-8069-4ccb-9775-63f96d1f4e53')/appRoleAssignedTo",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "zAXxTotQxEGl0n1B8iRMTPwz3O48iw9Oq3aFtqfYVjA",
            "deletedDateTime": null,
            "appRoleId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "createdDateTime": "2020-06-01T19:21:01.4268687Z",
            "principalDisplayName": "Nishant Singh",
            "principalId": "4ef105cc-508b-41c4-a5d2-7d41f2244c4c",
            "principalType": "User",
            "resourceDisplayName": "testspaquestion",
            "resourceId": "07fce81e-8069-4ccb-9775-63f96d1f4e53"
        },
        {
            "id": "Y3tbwNOvDkqKK9yLxJ5wp2-uBAbApk9LoMs6AN_7iSs",
            "deletedDateTime": null,
            "appRoleId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "createdDateTime": "2020-06-01T18:47:47.2702435Z",
            "principalDisplayName": "Sruthi J",
            "principalId": "c05b7b63-afd3-4a0e-8a2b-dc8bc49e70a7",
            "principalType": "User",
            "resourceDisplayName": "testspaquestion",
            "resourceId": "07fce81e-8069-4ccb-9775-63f96d1f4e53"
        },
        {
            "id": "CccjAFY1lkKmq23yoKERPBqNLldhOdBAm0lJzewK0Nk",
            "deletedDateTime": null,
            "appRoleId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "createdDateTime": "2020-07-23T17:34:53.9538274Z",
            "principalDisplayName": "Bgroup",
            "principalId": "0023c709-3556-4296-a6ab-6df2a0a1113c",
            "principalType": "Group",
            "resourceDisplayName": "testspaquestion",
            "resourceId": "07fce81e-8069-4ccb-9775-63f96d1f4e53"
        }
    ]
}
```

After querying the above, pull the principalid of each record and accordingly call user endpoint or group endpoint according to principaltype.

```
Get https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/4ef105cc-508b-41c4-a5d2-7d41f2244c4c //principalId
```

Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: Please let us know if this answer was helpful to you. If so, please remember to mark it as the answer using the check mark so that others in the community with similar questions can more easily find a solution. Also, Please spare few mins to let us know how we did using this link <https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9?Q_DL=Fa5t8dkcKtAi0la_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9_MLRP_5jQyS8SPt0bbbzT&Q_CHL=gl
>

Comment: Thank for this @Shiva.  One thing I later learned was the use of the /batch command, so that you can combine retrieving multiple user details at once. Frankly, it would be nice to be able to get both in one command.