# Filtering on expanded list

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Awhile ago I asked a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63058398/retrieve-user-details-and-roles-for-an-azure-ad-application-using-microsoft-grap).  I've since then discovered that this query gets me very close to what I'm looking for:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$expand=appRoleAssignments
```

with a return of

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(appRoleAssignments())",
    "value": [{
        "displayName": "Homer Simpson",
        "jobTitle": "Nuclear Engineer",
        "userPrincipalName": "homer@powerplant.com",
        "id": "fdd865df-2715-4637-adb4-ee81e8f7fbdc",
        "appRoleAssignments@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('fdd865df-2715-4637-adb4-ee81e8f7fbdc')/appRoleAssignments",
        "appRoleAssignments": [{
            "id": "ac-zitxw_Uiu2Lzm4rqdErfVvk5zpsVOnQlgbPkTgQo",
            "appRoleId": "cde6f719-acc1-419b-a085-dff24137265b",
            "principalDisplayName": "Homer Simpson",
            "principalId": "fdd865df-2715-4637-adb4-ee81e8f7fbdc",
            "principalType": "User",
            "resourceDisplayName": "my-nuclear-explosion",
            "resourceId": "d52ee6ae-70d7-4932-a89d-60d418828b41"
        }]
    }]
}
```

What I'm struggling with is trying to **filter** off the `appRoleAssignments.resourceId`, and am looking for help on how to achieve this.

Here are some of the following queries I've tried, and their errors:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$expand=appRoleAssignments($filter=resourceId eq d52ee6ae-70d7-4932-a89d-60d418828b41)

{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "Invalid $select properties."        
    }
}
```

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?&$expand=appRoleAssignments&$filter=appRoleAssignments/resourceId eq d52ee6ae-70d7-4932-a89d-60d418828b41

{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Invalid filter clause"
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi @Mark, I have tested many scenarios and it looks like the filter doesn't support on any of the properties in appRoleAssignments  on /users endpoint. Its better to filter it on our end using code. There is a way you can filter appRoleassignments using resourceid but its not that effective, which is if you get appRoleassignments for each user you can filter as below. `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/Shiva@nishantsingh.live/appRoleAssignments?$filter=resourceId eq 85649841-4b18-43f1-884e-8dce41d189f4`.

Comment: Thanks @ShivaKeshavVarma, that is helpful to know.  I found the `/beta` endpoint to have interesting results.  Not sure if that's a topic for another SO question, but `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$expand=appRoleAssignments($filter=resourceId eq 85649841-4b18-43f1-884e-8dce41d189f4)` doesn't complain about the filter here.  It does however A) not filter and B) somehow removes the appRoleAssignments.

Comment: Yeah, `beta` endpoints may change anytime. It's not recommended in production. Be sure while using it.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to filter by a guid then wrap the guid in single quotes.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$expand=appRoleAssignments&$filter=appRoleAssignments/resourceId eq 'd52ee6ae-70d7-4932-a89d-60d418828b41'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this still gives the Invalid Filter Clause error above

Comment: @MarkDeVerno I edited answer and removed "&" from "?&$expand". I've copied/pasted your code. It should be "?$expand"

Comment: Thanks for answering, but unfortunately, this still doesn't work.  Tried both the v1.0 and beta endpoints.  I've been using the https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer for validation.